# Decrypt XOR on Java

Tags: java, encryption, xor

Can any one help me write decrypt method for my XOR encryptor. So how i'm encrypt:

I'm making XOR

```
public static String idEncrypt(String id, String key)throws Exception
{
    if (id == null)
        return null;
    if (key.length() == 0)
        return id;
    String utfID="", utfKey="";
    try
    {
        utfID = new String(id.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
        utfKey = new String(key.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
    }
    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
    {
        Log.e("utf8", "conversion", e);
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0; i < utfID.length(); i++)
        sb.append((char)(utfID.charAt(i) ^ utfKey.charAt(i % utfKey.length())));
    String result = sb.toString();

    return toHex(result.getBytes());
}
```

Converting bytes to hex:

```
public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
    if (buf == null)
        return "";
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);
    for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
        appendHex(result, buf[i]);
    }
    return result.toString();
}

private final static String HEX = "0123456789abcdef";

private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
    sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
}
```

Actually all of my trying to decrypt result of this crypts failed =(
May be some on explains me how work with it?

P.S: the results of my trying is strings like "X¨»¾RkÖ_êQ", but must be 16 symbols of numbers and letters.

**UPD:** 
My fromHEX() method

```
 public static String fromHex(String hex) {
        return new String(toByte(hex));
    }

    public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
        int len = hexString.length()/2;
        byte[] result = new byte[len];
        for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
            result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: The inversion of XOR is XOR itself, so just convert from hex then XOR back. That said, I strongly recommend you use an algorithm such as AES instead of writing your own.

Comment: Please show your main method. It's unclear what you have and what you are trying to do with it. Since, you're encoding `toHex`, you will also need a `fromHex` method to run before decryption.

Comment: This shows a clear misunderstanding between bytes and characters, possibly because of prior exposure to the C `char` type (which is really a byte).  Note that XOR on two times `A` will result in the value `0`, which is not a printable character. Probably not what you want. So the question becomes: what *do* you want to implement?

Comment: XOR with a repeated key is probably only secure if the plaintext is completely random and unknown to an attacker. If it is a string, this is already not true. In short: don't.

Comment: So guys, thanks for help, actually my code is working, probably i think my key not correct. I'm wrote a couple of test and code work, except problem key which i'm get from one of user.

Comment: What do you mean, key you get from user? Simple XOR encryption is absolutely not fit to put in any production environment, and the code above certainly isn't either.